# Does ChatGPT have access to real-time data?

Tags: chatgpt, real-time, time

I wanted to see if ChatGPT knows the current time or not, and it persisted that it does not have access to any real-time data and its knowledge is limited to the year 2021 and before. But how does it know the date?
[image]

I also noticed its responses become better and better over time. Is it because it is directly instructed the way it should respond to some prompts?